# asp.net textbox won't show vertical scrollbar on iphone

Tags: asp.net, iphone

I have an company asp.net website with textboxes which may contain several hundred words.  These display just fine with a vertical scrollbar in Firefox and Safari on a Mac.  But on Safari on an iphone (the majority of users will have these) there is no vertical scrollbar.  Is there any way of forcing a vertical scrollbar?  If not, I guess I'm going to have to have separate pages with 'expanded' textboxes for the iphone users.

Asp.net textboxes don't have a 'scrollbar' property.  I've tried using an 'overflow:auto' style, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no scroll bar per-se for the iPhone. A two finger swipe/drag over the area causes it to scroll.

You could always implement a JavaScript based scroll bar.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

Comment: I've had an iphone for a year and didn't know about the 2 finger scroll!  However, I think our fat-fingered technicians may have a problem with this - your javascript solution looks pretty good.  Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel A. White thanks but your link is broken. But I searched and is this the updated address ? : http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/